# How to grant access to a folder using cacls on Windows XP?

Tags: cacls

I have revoked a permission for a folder test using cacls as follows.

```
cacls test /p username:n
```

It worked properly. I tried to unlock it using following command.

```
cacls test /p username:f
```

Command prompt showed this message

> Processed dir: D:\test

But still, I can't access the folder. Why?

Comment: Post result of `cacls test`